# ASP.NET MVC4 Multi-lingual Data Annotations

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, multilingual

In a standard application I have the following:

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Email Address")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

...this in turn generates a label for this form field automatically in English.

Now, if I need my app to support 5 languages, what is the best approach from a ASP.NET MVC application to handle this?

Scope of application is about 400 - 600 data fields.

UPDATE: I will also require support for updating small sections of text in the application like page names and introductions to each form (small paragraph).

Comment: What I did (and it was a cluster****) was something like: `[DisplayName(ResourceManager.GetTag("EmailAddress", GetCurrentLocale())]` - I created that class and methods and had it work but maybe there's a better built in way.

Comment: you can use resources for each language and use annotations.

Comment: @Serg - wouldn't that only work on the developer's workstation? As I understand it, attributes are serialized into the assembly metadata at compile time, so if you take your code to another country and run it, I think you'll still get whatever language it was compiled in.

Comment: `GetCurrentLocale()` isn't literally calling the .NET locale, it's just a name I used. It actually fetches a cookie value from the client. eg: `en-US, en-GB, es-ES`

Comment: Cheers for comments and answers, will work through these over the next week and then re-visit and mark answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of assigning the actual values to the attribute properties, assign keys for resource strings.  Then, you can use a custom `ModelMetadataProvider` that is aware of the localization context and will provide the appropriate string.  To get a better solution, you can make your custom `ModelMetadataProvider` infer conventions, (which cuts down on the need for verbose attributes).

Phil Haack has a blog article called [Model Metadata and Validation Localization using Conventions](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/07/14/model-metadata-and-validation-localization-using-conventions.aspx) that explains how this works.  There is also a corresponding NuGet package called [ModelMetadataExtensions](http://nuget.org/packages/ModelMetadataExtensionsWithBugfix) with source code available on github at https://github.com/Haacked/mvc-metadata-conventions .

*As a side note, I'd recommend reviewing some of the awesome answers I got on an old question of mine: [Effective Strategies for Localization in .NET](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/98358/effective-strategies-for-localization-in-net).  They don't specifically address your question, but will be very helpful if you are working on a multilingual .NET app.*

Comment: Does anybody have a similar solution like Phil Haack's for .NET Core 5.0 ?

Answer (score -1):

I would make custom attribute, like **[MyDisplayName("Section", "Key")]**
And this would provide translation based on selected language. Also check out database driven resources manager, like http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwDbResourceProvider/

Answer (score -1):

The best approach for localization is to store your strings in the database and not resource files unless,

1. Your app is very static
2. Your language set is very static

You can decorate your model with custom attribute where you set default string and DB id for the resource e.g.

```
[MyResource("email", 123)]
```

You can write custom http delegating handler to get resource out of cache (for example). Once you authenticate client, you know client's language demand and resource id. So, the client with Spanish and resource id = 1 will get "Si", the one with English will get "Yes". The resource id will be mapped to language-specific string.