# Retrieve Custom Data Annotations for create Custom LabelFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations, label-for

I am creating a custom `LabelFor`. Inside it want to get the `DataAnnotations` properties linked to attribute mainly `DataAnnotations` created by me and I'm not getting. Example: `Obrigatorio`

I need to get the values of `DataAnnotations` for the labelFor leave the fields in bold when required. And depending on the validation, leave customized with styles.

#### My Class

```
public class GrupoRisco : IEntidadeBase
{
    [Key]
    public int GrupoRiscoID { get; set; }
    [Obrigatorio]
    [Display(Name="Descrição")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

#### My Custom Atribute

```
public class Obrigatorio : RequiredAttribute
{
    public Obrigatorio()
    {
        ErrorMessage = "* Obrigatório";
    }
}
```

The attribute above is simple, but will create complex attributes.

Comment: You might want to approach localisation from a different perspective: http://blog.gauffin.org/2010/11/simplified-localization-for-dataannotations/

Comment: Also this can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12810022/809357

Comment: Validations are on the TextBoxFor or EditorFor, not LabelFor.

Comment: @StephenZeng I can not get the property to leave the label in bold when it is required?

Comment: if that's the only requirement and it doesn't involve validation then that should be fairly straightforward. You don't even need to derive from required attribute. Just check if the property is marked as required.