# How to translate the default ModelErrors in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net

In my app, I have custom ModelErrors set, with a fixed message in my case in spanish, for example:

```
if (tripOdometer <= 0)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Odometer", $"Inserte una distancia superior a la última almacenada, que fue de {lastFuelingEntryOdometer}");
    return View(request);
}
```

But my problem is that the errors that come with DataAnnotations package are in english (logically), and produce in my case a spanglish output.

A property in one of my models:

```
[Required]
[Range(1970, 2021)]
[Display(Name = "Año de Fabricación")]
public int Year { get; set; }
```

OUTPUTS:
The Año de Fabricación field is required.
The field Año de Fabricación must be between 1970 and 2021.

Is it possible to translate them, in a general way for all the models and properties?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12810022/1139830) solve your question? I know it's for non-Core but I'm not sure how much of it still applies.

Comment: Lot of info in the linked post. Didn't find for myself an easy way to do it, and seems that there isn't but I will investigate in the links that are provided in that question u mention. Thanks u a lot.